# java regex help

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in the following format, I only need to extract the `/jspFolderTestSecondLast/jspFolderTestLast`, 
which is the second last seperated by /.

```
www.name.com/jspFolderTestOne/jspFolderTestTwo/jspFolderTestAndmanyMore/jspFolderTestSecondLast/jspFolderTestLast
```

`/jspFolderTestSecondLast/jspFolderTestLast` can be varied in length but always gonna be separated by secong last /.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As usual: what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any regexes for that, since you can just split the string on '/' and get two last array indexes. But here's the regex anyway:

```
^.+(/[^/]+)(/[^/]+)$
```

$1 contains the first and $2 contains the second block

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "www.name.com/jspFolderTestOne/jspFolderTestTwo/jspFolderTestAndmanyMore/jspFolderTestSecondLast/jspFolderTestLast"
String[] parts = s.split("/");
String whatYouWant = parts[parts.length-2] +"/" + parts[parts.length-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "www.name.com/jspFolderTestOne/jspFolderTestTwo/jspFolderTestAndmanyMore/jspFolderTestSecondLast/jspFolderTestLast";

String are[]  = str.split("/");//may be you need to add escape here
//take last two parts
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(/[^/]+/[^/]+)$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("a/b/c/d.txt");
    if( m.matches() ) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the javascript version:

```
"www.name.com/jspFolderTestOne/jspFolderTestTwo/jspFolderTestAndmanyMore/jspFolderTestSecondLast/jspFolderTestLast".search(/\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*$/)
```

or you can group them nicely:

`(/(\/[^\/]*)(\/[^\/]*)$/)`